# SDL Trados Studio Plugin (Batch Task) - FileBasedProject CurrentProject Property

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on a project in C# .Net to create a Plugin for the translation software SDL Trados Studio. The plugin should, among other things, output the name of the current project where the plugin is used.
The [documentation](https://developers.rws.com/studio-api-docs/api/integration/Sdl.TranslationStudioAutomation.IntegrationApi.ProjectsController.html#Sdl_TranslationStudioAutomation_IntegrationApi_ProjectsController_CurrentProject) says it can be done using the declaration:
`public FileBasedProject CurrentProject { get; }`
How can I retrieve the name of the current project?

I have tried to use the following code (see below). Shouldn't it retrieve the current project I'm working in when using the plugin?:
`private FileBasedProject _project;`
...which should make it possible to use:
Console.WriteLine(_project.CurrentProject)?

I got everything working in that (quite simple) C# program but this. Can you help me out?